# Wrong order during sorting at first by predefined order, and then by natural order using Comparator method thenComparing()

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I have a simple object class:

```
public class Employee {
    String name;
    String secondName;
 // Conctructor, getters & setters
}
```

List of employees:

```
        List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
                new Employee("Jake",  "Bbb"),
                new Employee("Ann",   "Aaa"),
                new Employee("Ivy",   "Bbb"),
                new Employee("Ivy",   "Aaa"),
                new Employee("Jake",  "Aaa"),
                new Employee("Tom",   "Iii"),
                new Employee("Neil",  "Xxx"),
                new Employee("Keith", "Ooo"),
                new Employee("Tom",   "Rrr")
        ));
```

I want to sort them in predefined order of secondNames first and than in natural order of names:

```
List<String> definedOrder = Arrays.asList("Iii", "Bbb", "Aaa");
```

in such way:

```
employees.sort(
        Comparator.comparing((Employee e) -> definedOrder.indexOf(e.getSecondName()))
                .thenComparing(Employee::getName));

for (Employee em : employees){
     System.out.println(em.getSecondName() + " / " + em.getName());
}
```

And I experct to recive the predifined objects in the list first, then the rest objects:

```
Iii / Tom
Bbb / Ivy
Bbb / Jake
Aaa / Ann
Aaa / Ivy
Aaa / Jake
Ooo / Keith
Xxx / Neil
Rrr / Tom
```

But I receive objects firstly sorted in the natural order by *name*s, (using thenComparing() method), and then from predefined comparison by *secondName*s:

```
Ooo / Keith
Xxx / Neil
Rrr / Tom
Iii / Tom
Bbb / Ivy
Bbb / Jake
Aaa / Ann
Aaa / Ivy
Aaa / Jake
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing that `definedOrder.indexOf(e.getSecondName())` returns `-1` when second name is not found in `definedOrder`.

That's why `Ooo`, `Xxx` and `Rrr` appear before `Iii`, `Bbb`, and `Aaa`.

And, as `Ooo`, `Xxx` and `Rrr` all share the same value (`-1`) for the purposes of `comparing`, they are sorted by `thenComparing(Employee::getName))` among themselves.

---

To fix this behavior, you can check if `definedOrder.indexOf(e.getSecondName())` returns `-1` and, if so, return `Integer.MAX_VALUE` instead.